# J2ME use left right buttons on the high lvl UI?

Tags: java-me, mobile, nokia

I am using the High level UI "Forms, Alert, textBox....". I need to use the left and right buttons to do something in a choices.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are asking about menu in the form. see this [wiki link.](http://wiki.forum.nokia.com/index.php/How_to_create_an_advanced_menu_in_Java_ME_using_the_low-level_graphical_API) It will helps you.

Comment: Actually I want to use the high level UI, your link lead to use the low level one.